# How do you conditionally modify a UINavigationController's back-stack to skip previous entries regardless of where you came from?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, unwind-segue, stack-unwinding

We're trying to figure out how to conditionally exclude certain screens in our back-stack when navigating backwards. For instance, take the following screens:

1. Main Dashboard (You can go to 2 or 3 from here)
2. Order Management (you can go to 3 or 6 from here)
3. Enter Order
4. Review Order
5. Order Confirmation (if you make it here, back should skip 3 & 4)
6. Order Status (if you make it here, back should skip 5 (it already skips 3 & 4))

Screens 3-5 represent entering an order so if you've made it to the confirmation page, we don't want you going back to the review or edit pages.

For the same reason, if you've navigated to 'Order Status' from the confirmation page, we don't want you navigating back to the 'Order Confirmation', but rather back to 'Order Management' or 'Main Dashboard' (depending on how you got there)

> Note: We're aware of popToViewController and how it lets you skip over all controllers between where you are and the one you specify. The issue is I don't know what that view controller is. I only know which I want to skip over (if they are present.) More importantly, the back button reflects what's in the stack, not what I'm popping to. That's why I'm hoping to tell the system 'Just ignore these in the stack when going back'. Hope that makes sense.

My crude attempt is to modify the back stack like so...

```
func showConfirmation() {

    guard navigationController = navigationController else {
        return
    }

    navigationController.pushViewController(orderConfirmation, animated:true)

    if let orderEntryIndex  = navigationController.viewControllers.index(of:orderEntry),
       let orderReviewIndex = navigationController.viewControllers.index(of:orderReview){

        navigationController.viewControllers.removeSubrange(orderEntryIndex...orderReviewIndex)
    }
}

func showStatus() {

    guard navigationController = navigationController else {
        return
    }

    navigationController.pushViewController(orderStatus, animated:true)

    if let orderConfirmationIndex = navigationController.viewControllers.index(of:orderConfirmation){

        navigationController.viewControllers.remove(at: orderConfirmationIndex)
    }
}
```

> Note: This is simplified code. We don't actually hang onto instances of the view controllers. We find the indexes by looking for their type in the back-stack. This is for simple illustrative purposes only.

While the navigation works, during the animation, the back button shows the original back location, then after the animation, the label's value 'snaps' to show the new back location.  This of course proves this isn't the right approach.

I know there are unwind segues, but that worries about where you're going. We just want to remove items from the backlog after navigating away from them, but otherwise leave the back-stack intact.

So how does one achieve this behavior of ignoring prior steps?

Comment: I haven't tried this because I don't have navigation that's complex enough to require it but you might find it useful: http://irace.me/navigation-coordinators  (Also: http://khanlou.com/2015/10/coordinators-redux/)

Comment: Are you using the storyboard to create the segue's for the Back button?

Comment: No, not on a storyboard.  I think I found it though... navigationController?.setViewControllers(:, animated:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out how to do it, and have added an extension on UINavigationController to help with this in the future.

The secret is to use the `setViewControllers` method to replace the entire set of `UIViewController` objects, removing the ones you want to skip.  To facilitate that, I pass in an array of `UIViewController.Type`s which I use to filter out the existing controllers which I don't want.

```
extension UINavigationController {

    func pushViewController(_ viewController:UIViewController, removingBackItemsOfType backItemTypesToRemove:[UIViewController.Type], animated:Bool) {

        var viewControllers = self.viewControllers
            .filter{ vc in !backItemTypesToRemove.contains(where:{ vcType in vcType == type(of:vc) } ) }

        viewControllers.append(viewController)

        setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

So now, when I'm on 'Review Order', I use this method to push to 'Order Confirmation' passing in the items I want to remove from the back-stack, like so...

```
let orderConfirmation = OrderConfirmation()

let typesToRemove:[UIViewController.Type] = [
    EnterOrder.self,
    ReviewOrder.self
]

navigationController?.pushViewController(orderConfirmation, removingBackItemsOfType:typesToRemove, animated:true)
```

The result is it pushes to the new Order Confirmation view controller, but pressing back brings me to whatever screen I was at before Enter Order, regardless of where I came from.

I then do the same when pushing from Order Confirmation to Order Status, this time removing `[OrderConfirmation.self]`.  Same thing... back now brings me to the screen that launched me into Order Entry.

In short, this lets you set up the scenarios I described above without having to worry about what came before. Just what you want to skip.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you help me out please? What I tried first is adding your code in my current viewcontroller, so I added in that array my CurrentViewController, when I go back using dismiss and instead of going to where I want to, it shows a black screen with nav bar, let's say from here works fine because from that back button in my nav bar it goes exactly where I want to go. Then I figured out I should call that extension before enter my current view controller, but in that case it shows me a warning "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions". Thanks

Comment: Never mind, I figured out, my solution was more like Shehzad's approach and setting "false" in your removingBackItemsOfType. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Prior your condition you can check the view controllers list in the navigation stack and pop to the view controller you want

```
    for controller in (self.navigationController?.viewControllers)! {
        if controller is SomeClass {
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(controller, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: This won't work because this requires you to know where you're going, not where you don't want to stop.  Also, this is a 'pop' operation whereas we want it to look like a 'push' operation (i.e. the animation is backwards.)